# Wordpress Plugin: Where to put "maxlength="10" to limit formfield character count?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the plugin "strong testimonials". 
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/strong-testimonials/
I need to limit the maximum characters a user can type in the comment form.
When inspecting my page, the form is rendered as

```
<textarea id="wpmtst_post_content" name="post_content" class="" required="" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

I just need to append "maxlength="10" attribute, but since the HTML code is assembled with php, i can't find where to put it in which php file. I noticed the form fields are stored in arrays, which will be exploded upon request, but I don't know anything about PHP and can't figure out, where I have to put it. 
Thanks
AO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change PHP code, you can do it with javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wpmtst_post_content').attr('maxlength',10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="wpmtst_post_content" name="post_content" class="" required="" tabindex="0" aria-required="true"></textarea>
```